# wso2 emm mysql devices table empty

Tags: android, mysql, database, agent, wso2-iot

Working on WSO 2 EMM on debian JAVA6 64 bits with Mysql.

Datasource is configured correctly, I can see users in WSO2CARBON_DB.
I create a user, download the agent on android and register to the server

On the interface, I can see the Android phone but it is not in the table devices in mysql WSO2EMM_DB.

else, I don't have the application list in the interface

No error messages in the console, it's wierd
And after a while, the phone doesn't update information anymore.

Any idea ?

Antoine

Answer (score 0):

Maybe data is not committed to the database. please follow the below doc and see the topic 'How to migrate from H2 to MySQL' and see whether you have configured it correctly.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release

Answer (score 0):

Ye I did that, by the way there is an error in master-datasources.xml

the following line has to be added just after  for mysql

```
<defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
```

or it won't work. Else I had to rename field wifi_mac into mac in devices table

The problem is only for insert in devices

Just came back to H2 database and it works fine.